# Is there any way to use webhook only is there is a push on specific branch?

Tags: jenkins, webhooks

I want to trigger a jenkins job only when there is a push on a specific git branch, but unfortunately couldn't find anything.
Thank you.

Comment: In the Git configuration, did you configure the "Branches to build" parameter to build your specific branch?

Comment: @bruno : Yes, I have mentioned it in git configuration, but the thing Is I don't want to trigger job when there Is no commit on the specified branch lets say **foo** branch. what I think Is we have to do something on the git side, but git doesn't have any plugin to add webhook for a specific branch commit.

Comment: @RohanNagalkar did you get chance to make it work?

Comment: @ArbabNazar Nope I coudn't but what I did Is I created a job in such a way that It will just clone the code In temp directory and then again it will go to the path of the actual code and clone for the specific branch mentioned in jenkins parameter and process accordingly,

Comment: @RohanNagalkar can you share the job config/details.

Answer (score 0):

Under Source Code Management you would have selected Git option,There is an option Branches to build mention only the branch you wish to build e.g. foo

[image]

Further more there is a GitHub Branch Plugin in Jenkins, which allows you to add restrictions on branches, and provides more control on branches and how to build specific branches, you can find this option in trigger events-->Branch Restrictions

[image]

Hope this helps :)